# httplib2.SSLHandshakeError while Installing Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, httplib2, google-cloud-sdk

While installing the Google Cloud SDK - Python, a httplib2.SSLHandshakeError keeps occuring. I have configured the unfilled_client_secrets.json (shown below the return). And this has not solved the HandshakeError.

Similar questions have been asked on here below, but none have been explicitly answered.  Thank you, in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

> ~ $ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh    Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/Users/rptrainor/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py",
>   line 206, in 
>       main()
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py",
>   line 184, in main
>       Install(pargs.override_components, pargs.additional_components)
>   File
>   "/Users/rptrainor/./google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py",
>   line 130, in Install
>       _CLI.Execute(['--quiet', 'components', 'list'])
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py",
>   line 759, in Execute
>       self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
>   File
>   "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py",
>   line 737, in Execute
>       resources = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py",
>   line 741, in Run
>       display_info=self.ai.display_info).Display()
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/display.py",
>   line 427, in Display
>       self._printer.Print(self._resources)
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/resource/resource_printer_base.py", line 251, in Print
>       for resource in resources:
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/components/list.py",
>   line 86, in Run
>       result = update_manager.List()
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py",
>   line 516, in List
>       _, diff = self._GetStateAndDiff(command_path='components.list')
>   File
>   "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py",
>   line 446, in _GetStateAndDiff
>       command_path=command_path)
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py",
>   line 429, in _GetLatestSnapshot
>       *effective_url.split(','), command_path=command_path)
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/snapshots.py",
>   line 165, in FromURLs
>       for url in urls]
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/snapshots.py",
>   line 186, in _DictFromURL
>       response = installers.ComponentInstaller.MakeRequest(url, command_path)
>   File
>   "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/installers.py",
>   line 283, in MakeRequest
>       return url_opener.urlopen(req, timeout=timeout)
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/url_opener.py",
>   line 69, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(req, data, timeout)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 404, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 422, in _open
>       '_open', req)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 382, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/url_opener.py",
>   line 54, in https_open
>       return self.do_open(build, req)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
>   line 1181, in do_open
>       h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)   File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 995, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 1029, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 991, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 844, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py",
>   line 806, in send
>       self.connect()
>   File "/Users/rptrainor/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/**init**.py",
>   line 1081, in connect
>       raise SSLHandshakeError(e)
>
> httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL >routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

```
{
  "web":{
    "client_id":"[[CLIENT_ID_IS_HERE]]",
    "project_id":"[[PROJECT_ID_IS_HERE]]",
    "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret":"[[CLIENT_SECRET_IS_HERE]]"
    }
}
```

Comment: having same issue with App Engine python SDK 1.92.53 while deploying  a new version.

Comment: This usually happens when the issue is with Python installation or environment. You can try updating Python to a latest version and see if works. Are you behind a proxy network or a firewall? Can you test it out connecting to an open network?

Answer (score 3):

Try updating Python to the last 2.7.x version. I could resolve the very same issue updating Python to 2.7.13.

Comment: "brew install python@2"  and "conda upgrade python" can both do this, depending on which is applicable (both are on my mac)

Answer (score 0):

One silly yet effective solution could be accessing these URL's via browser once and accepting their certificate.

As well check the time of your computer. If it is not appropriate i mean not in the current date. Server will not share the certificate.